# LinqConnect to develop database driven Windows 8 Metro Application?

Tags: windows-8

Can I use [LinqConnect](http://devart.com/linqconnect/) to develop database driven Windows 8 Metro Application for small businesses?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, yes.  If you [visit their site](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/download.html), you'll see the following:

[image]